# Prove a finite cover contains {$⁡B_r (x_i)|x_i \in X$} for every $r>0$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

If $X$ is a compact subset in metric space. Prove that there does not exist an infinite cover of $X$ that contains {$⁡B_r (x_i)|x_i \in X$},  $\forall r>0$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have a clear idea of what you are trying to prove? I don't given your description of the question: if you mean that every ball $B_r(x_i) \cap A$ belongs to the cover, then that can't be true unless $A$ is finite. If you mean that every ball $B_r(x_i)$ in the ambient space is contained in the union of the cover, that can't be true unless the ambient space is bounded.

Comment: Which definition of "compact" do you use?

Comment: Why have you deleted a big part of your question? The deleted part contained essential information concerning what you want to know.

Comment: @Paul Frost I doubt whether it should remain. Because it seems that proving by constructive method is not that obvious, though it is correct, and thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any $x_1 \in A$. If $A \not\subset B(x_1;r)$, then pick any $x_2 \in A \setminus B(x_1;r)$. If $A \not\subset B(x_1;r) \cup B(x_2;r) $, then pick any $x_3 \in A \setminus (B(x_1;r) \cup B(x_2;r))$. Continue this process. Then either $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i;r)$) for some $n$ and the process stops, or you can continue picking $x_{n+1} \in A  \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i;r)$ ad infinitum and get an infinite sequence $(x_i)$ in $A$.

We shall show that such a sequence is impossible.

Since $A$ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence $(x_{i_k})$ with limit $x \in A$. Thus $d(x_{i_k},x) < r/2$ for $k \ge K$. We conclude $d(x_{i_K},x_{i_{K+1}}) \le d(x_{i_k},x) + d(x,x_{i_{K+1}}) < r/2 + r/2 = r$. This means $x_{i_{K+1}} \in B(x_{i_K};r) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{i_{K+1}-1} B(x_i;r)$ which contradicts the construction of $x_{i_{K+1}}$.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: May I ask in the last step why $B(x_{i_k};r) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{i_{K+1}-1} B(x_i;r)$?

Comment: Can I write it in this way: $x_{m+1} \in B(x_{m};r) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} B(x_i;r)$

Comment: I had a typo, it should have been $B(x_{i_K};r)$ instead of $B(x_{i_k};r)$. We have $i_K <  i_{K+1}$, thus $i_K \in \{1,\ldots,i_{K+1} -1 \}$ and $B(x_{i_K};r) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{i_{K+1}-1} B(x_i;r)$. But you cannot argue that $x_{m+1} \in B(x_m;r)$ for some $m$ because we may have $i_{K+1} > i_K + 1$.

Comment: Got it! thanks a lot